# Trying with Nightwatch + Browserstack to set up a simple login test, failing

Tags: automation, nightwatch.js, browserstack

Using `"nightwatch": "^1.0.11"` and `"browserstack-local": "^1.3.4"`

I have tried this many ways, but I cannot get the examples in the documentation to run.

I have a simple login page with a page object

```
module.exports = {
    url: function() {
      return this.api.launchUrl + '/login';
    },
    elements: {
        email: {
            selector: '#user_login_email'
        },
        password: {
            selector: '#user_login_password'
        },
        button: {
            selector: '#login-btn'
        }
    }
};
```

I then want to run a test to login into the site (NOTE: The first screenshot is fine)

```
module.exports = {
    before(client) {
        client.maximizeWindow();
    },

    'Login' : function (client) {
        var login = client.page.login();

        login.navigate();

        client.waitForElementPresent('body', 500)
            .saveScreenshot('tests_output/login.png');

        login.setValue('@email', 'test@user.email')
            .setValue('@password', 'Pa55w0rd')
            .click('@button');

        client.pause(1000)
            .saveScreenshot('tests_output/login-complete.png');
    },

    after(client) {
        client.end();
    }
};
```

I get the following errors when trying to run the test through browserstack (with the local URL)

```
✖ login.test
 – Login (5.196s)

  An error occurred while running .setValue() command on <Element [name=@email]>: Error: First argument passed to .elementIdValue() should be a web element ID string. Received object.
      at Function.validateElementId (node_modules/nightwatch/lib/api/protocol.js:36:19)
      at ProtocolActions.elementIdValue (node_modules/nightwatch/lib/api/protocol.js:951:25)
      at transport.locateElement.then.result (node_modules/nightwatch/lib/api-loader/element-command.js:106:54)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)


  An error occurred while running .setValue() command on <Element [name=@password]>: Error: First argument passed to .elementIdValue() should be a web element ID string. Received object.
[...]

  An error occurred while running .click() command on <Element [name=@button]>: Error: First argument passed to .elementIdClick() should be a web element ID string. Received object.
[...]
```

I have gotten successful tests to run; just not using the documented examples.

For example, the below code works fine to close a cookie message

```
client
    .waitForElementPresent('.cookie-message__button', 5, true, function(result) {
        client.elementIdClick(result.value[0].ELEMENT);
    })
    .saveScreenshot('tests_output/cookie-closed.png');
```

But obviously it's really long winded.

Any help for what I'm doing wrong would be awesome.

Using the following as an example for the Nightwatch config: https://github.com/browserstack/nightwatch-browserstack/blob/master/conf/local.conf.js with the local runner and running tests in parallel in 3 browsers: https://github.com/browserstack/nightwatch-browserstack/blob/master/scripts/local.runner.js

TL;DR: Documentation examples don't work with version 1.0.11; but Nightwatch and Browserstack are configured correctly as can get a suite to run (in Travis and locally), just with very long-winded code, which I hacked together.

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample project for page objects model [here](https://github.com/Kannamaraj/nightwatch-browserstack). Also, [sample login test](https://github.com/Kannamaraj/nightwatch-browserstack/blob/master/tests/pages/login.js) is added using `page_objects_path`.

The compatibility for latest nightwatch version is also added. The latest version of nightwatch seems to have changes which are in compliant with w3c. So we need to use `'browserName'` as capability instead of `'browser'`

Comment: Thanks; but I already tried `browserName` and it made no difference.  I cannot see any changes that you've made that I didn't already try.

Comment: There is also an open issue on Nightwatch.js about the broken selectors. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1237